# PHP PDO insert operation failing

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PDO and I am having a problem with the following insert operation. It ends up always in the else case (returning 0).

```
function insertInclusao($usuarioId, $tipoFaturaId, $parametrosValidadores, $identificadorExtra, $optin) {
    $pdoConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass");
    try {
        $stmte = $pdoConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO SF_INCLUSAO (UsuarioId, TipoFaturaId, ParametrosValidadores, DataInclusao, IdentificadorExtra, Optin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?)");
        $stmte->bindParam(1, $usuarioId , PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmte->bindParam(2, $tipoFaturaId , PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmte->bindParam(3, $parametrosValidadores , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmte->bindParam(4, $identificadorExtra , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmte->bindParam(5, $optin , PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $executarInclusao = $stmte->execute();
        if($executarInclusao) {
            return $pdoConnection->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       return -1;
    }
}
```

It used to work when I was using mysql_query like this:

```
 function insertInclusao($usuarioId, $tipoFaturaId, $parametrosValidadores, $identificadorExtra, $optin) {
    $db_connection = mysql_connect( "host", "user", "pass" ) or die( mysql_error() );
    mysql_select_db( "database" ) or die( mysql_error() );
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO SF_INCLUSAO (UsuarioId, TipoFaturaId, ParametrosValidadores, DataInclusao, IdentificadorExtra, Optin) VALUES ('".$usuarioId."', '".$tipoFaturaId."', '".$parametrosValidadores."', NOW(), '".$identificadorExtra."', '".$optin."');";
    $query_return = mysql_query($insert_query);
    $new_id = mysql_insert_id();
    if($query_return) {
        return $new_id; // OK
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Right now I am failing to see what could be wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: change `catch (PDOException $e) {
       $e->getMessage();
    }` and check exact error message.

Comment: Doesn't get there, it falls into the else case, returning 0.

Comment: write `else{print_r($pdoConnection->errorInfo());}` and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this

```
$pdoConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdoConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

You will now get the error because you have set the PDO error mode to exception.

```
function insertInclusao($usuarioId, $tipoFaturaId, $parametrosValidadores, $identificadorExtra, $optin) {
$pdoConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass");
$pdoConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdoConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
try {
    $stmte = $pdoConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO SF_INCLUSAO (UsuarioId, TipoFaturaId, ParametrosValidadores, DataInclusao, IdentificadorExtra, Optin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?)");
    $stmte->bindParam(1, $usuarioId , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmte->bindParam(2, $tipoFaturaId , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmte->bindParam(3, $parametrosValidadores , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmte->bindParam(4, $identificadorExtra , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmte->bindParam(5, $optin , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $executarInclusao = $stmte->execute();
    if($executarInclusao) {
        return $pdoConnection->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   return $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: Those two lines helped find the problem. It was one of the inserted values that was not matching the database structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

`$pdoConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass",array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`

and then you can change this:

```
if($executarInclusao) {
    return $pdoConnection->lastInsertId();
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

for this:

```
return $pdoConnection->lastInsertId();
```

Because if something go wrong with query, `$stmte->execute()` throw PDOException